# Does Federated Authentication improve persistent user performance?

Tags: performance, federated-authentication

In Sitecore 9, does Federated Authentication improve the performance limitations for persistent users? It appears to wrap around .NET Membership, which is the same as previous versions.

(Credit goes to Jeroen de Groot for the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a note, user persistence is optional with Federated Authentication.

Federated Authentication supports both virtual users and a membership-backed user. It is also possible to roll your own persistence if required.

Since the underlying Membership storage structure is unchanged, the same scaling limits apply as with previous versions.

**NOTE:** The official documentation site has an article on [how to configure persistent users](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/configure_federated_authentication#_Configure_virtual_and).

Comment: How can i create user persistence with Federated Authentication ? Any clue..

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Some code samples on the answer would be helpful vs the only link answer :-)

Comment: Agreed, Dylan, had the question about how to do it been asked as a Question I would provide a more full answer, but it was not directly related to the original question.